# How do I access objects created during the runtime of a method in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, orm

I have a class with a `Klass::save` method.  This method will create a new instance of Klass, and then call either `inst.create` or `inst.update` depending.

I want to write an rspec test like this:

`expect(instance_created_within_class_method).to receive(:create)`

Can I access an object that is created during the running of the method I'm testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect_any_instance_of(Class).to receive(:create)` may be what you're looking for.

To call through the method you can add `.and_call_original` to the end of it.

Check out the RSpec documentation surrounding mocks and expectations: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class!